# Marlin Firmware - Autostart only runs `auto1.g` but not `auto0.g`

Tags: marlin, firmware

Marlin has a feature that can [execute a G-code file from an SD card when printer is turned on](https://marlinfw.org/docs/features/autostart.html); this is called Autostart.

> `Autostart` is available on printers with an SD card reader. If `auto0.g` exists on the card, the printer will recognize and execute it on bootup. Thereafter, if there are files with incrementing numbers, e.g. `auto1.g`, they will be done in incrementing order.

Name your file `auto0.g` and it runs when the printer is powered up.  `auto0.g` should execute first then `auto1.g` then `auto2.g` etc.  Mine will only execute `auto1.g` and not the others. Any thoughts what happens here?

Comment: Hi Sea Wa, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Do the skipped files contain valid G-code? Are the files properly ended Unix/Windows line breaking? Files or SD-card corrupt?

Comment: Thank you for you response. Could you please explain what the proper ending Unix/Window line breaking is.

Comment: would it be practical to test each auto file individually prior to creating the cascade?

Comment: I tried auto0.g alone and it executed. I am using Marlin 2.0.6 0n a BTT SKR 1.4 Turbo with TMC 2209 drivers. One my Ender 3 Pro with auto0.g, auto1.g and auto2.g on SD card, it will execute auto0.g but not the others.

Comment: what if you rename auto1.g to auto0.g and run it alone? If there's a problem with the code, it would appear. Each successive auto file could be tested this way.

Comment: Thanks, tried that. Each file runs when named auto0.g and is the only file on the SD card. I tried a number of combinations all with the same results.

Comment: Thanks, tried that already.  Each independent file will execute when named to auto0.g.